# Get all the commits which have some piece of code (added/updated/deleted) for a given author

Tags: git, git-log

I want to check for a given author, how many commits has he committed when he was playing around with some given piece of code?

E.g:- Let us say an author, **A** has added `Hello World!` somewhere in file in the git repository and commited it. Then, he moved that line to another file and commited it. And finally, he completely removed it from git ecosystem. I want all  3 commits in my output.

> I ran into this use-case while back. I googled and did some experiments after reading some online git log documentations. Therefore, I thought of sharing the knowledge with a bigger audience. Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the following code:

```
git log --all -S "<Piece of code>" --author="<Author's Name/Email>"
```

Here, `-S "<Piece of code>"` will ask git to search for the commit logs with `piece of code` input, and then `--author="<Author's Name/Email>"` will apply an additional filter to check for desired author.

**Note**: input to `--author` is *case sensitive*. One can resolve this issue by adding `-i` to above command.

```
git log --all -S "<Piece of code>" -i --author="<Author's Name/Email>"
```